# Node.js - simple Restify POST Mocha test failing

Tags: node.js, http-post, mocha.js, restify

I have a simple Node.js  Rest server with a single POST service using Restify. I am trying to write a simple Mocha test, however it fails with a timeout, although succeeds with a REST Console test (browser plugin).

My server code:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies
 */

var restify = require('restify');
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');


/**
 * Create App
 */

var server = restify.createServer({
  name: 'test',
    version: '0.0.1'
    });

var eventsEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

/**
 * Configuraion
 */

server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());


/**
 * Routes
 */


server.post('/post', function (req, res, next) {
  var text = "";
  req.setEncoding("utf8");

  req.on("data", function (chunk) {
    text += chunk;
  });
  req.on("end", function () {
    res.send(200, {ok: 'ok'});   
  });

  return next();
});


/**
 * Listen
 */ 

server.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

The Mocha test is as follows:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var assert = require('assert');

// init the test client
var client = restify.createJsonClient({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
  version: '*'
});

describe('service: post endpoint', function() {

// Test #1
describe('200 response check', function() {
    it('should get a 200 response', function(done) {
        client.post('/post', { hello: 'world' }, function(err, req, res, data) {                
            if (err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            }
            else {

                if (data.code != 200) {
                    throw new Error('invalid response from /post');
                }
                done();
            }
        });
    });
});

});
```

Can anyone advise why the test would timeout (I have tested with increasing the timeout in Mocha), but succeed through a browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Restify calls your `server.post('/post', handler)` function when the request is finished being received. You don't have to wait for the `data` and `end` events. It is something that Restify (and other libraries like it, eg. Express) do for you. So all you need to do is write

```
server.post('/post', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(200, {ok: 'ok'});
});
```

And then you should not have a timeout. You were having the timeout because your handler was waiting for events that *already* came.